# Coming back to an Activity after making a phone call

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to make a phone call and after the call ends I want to come back the `Activity` which started a call.

Code to start a call :

```
// Start a call
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Code to handle coming back to activity :

```
// Monitor phone call activities
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    String TAG = "PhoneCallListener";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        // If call ringing
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Call ringing, number : " + incomingNumber);
        }
        // Else if call active
        else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Call active");

            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }
        // Else if call idle
        else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Call idle");

            if (isPhoneCalling) {

                isPhoneCalling = false;

                // Finish native call application to come back to this
                // activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getIntent());
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Using `finish()` does not work. It stays on call application.

How do I come back to the `Activity` that started a phone call?

Comment: have you tried `startActivityForResult()`? It might be that the phone call app simply refuses to automatically go back...

Comment: yes, call startActivityForResult() and see how it behaves.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Tried it. Does not work.

Comment: Than I doubt that you can do that.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Calling `finishActivity(10)` does not even call `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: but does it finish the call app?

Comment: You cannot use `startActivityForResult()` because the phone call is made by another application which is running in a different task.

Comment: If you don't call `finish()` on the activity that started the call, after the call completes doesn't it return there? I don't see why it wouldn't just do that automatically.

Comment: @WarrenFaith No it does not finish the call app.

Comment: @DavidWasser No, it does not return without doing anything.

Comment: I doubt that it can be done. I guess the phone call app just refuses to close itself. I also can't remember that I have ever seen an app continuing itself after a call happened.

Comment: @WarrenFaith There are lot of question on SO asking how to come back to app after a phone call and people answer to them. So I believe it is possible just their solutions does not work in my case.

Comment: And how about telling us which solution you have tried? You are not even telling us which Android version you are using or if real device or emulator...

Comment: @WarrenFaith Look at the answer I posted.

Comment: which answered none of my questions...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33528/discussion-between-akash-and-warrenfaith)